# Query Between 2 Tables, Merge the results. Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my scenario:

Tab1:

```
id  value
1   x
2   y
3   z
```

Tab2:

```
id  value
2   o
```

Output:

```
id  value
1   x
2   o
3   z
```

I need to extract values from two tables and merge the results.
If there is an ID in Tab2 that is contained in Tab1 too I need to replace that value in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Tab1.id
 , COALESCE(Tab2.value, Tab1.value ) AS the_value
FROM Tab1 
LEFT JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.id = Tab2.id
    ;
```

Comment: this is a perfect solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab208/1/0) for the following query:

```
SELECT Tab1.id, CASE WHEN Tab2.value IS NULL THEN Tab1.value ELSE Tab2.value END
FROM Tab1 
LEFT JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.id = Tab2.id
```

If there could be records in `Tab2` that are not in `Tab1` then you could use the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2153d/8/1)):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Tab1.id IS NULL THEN Tab2.id ELSE Tab1.id END,
       CASE WHEN Tab2.value IS NULL THEN Tab1.value ELSE Tab2.value END
FROM Tab1 
FULL JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.id = Tab2.id;
```

Or

```
SELECT COALESCE(Tab2.id, Tab1.id) AS id, 
       COALESCE(Tab2.value, Tab1.value) AS tvalue
FROM Tab1 
FULL JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.id = Tab2.id;
```